# Unexpected Behavior: JQuery Mobile Page Scrolling to Next Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have created a JQuery Mobile web app that is experiencing an unexpected behavior: when the user clicks on a list item, the details page loads, however, you can scroll down past the bottom of the details page, and part of the list view shows up.

Here is a url to the latest build of the project: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B1/index.html

The Javascript Page that dynamically generates the details pages: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B1/landmarks.js

I am guessing that the problem is in the `createLandmarkPage()` function of landmarks.js. The 2 functions that control the creation of the pages are reproduced below:

```
function assembleLandmarkPages(landmarkList){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var totalLandmarkHTML = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < landmarkList.length; i++)
        {
            //console.log(landmarkList[i]);
            totalLandmarkHTML += createLandmarkPage(landmarkList[i]);
        }

        //console.log(totalLandmarkHTML);
        document.getElementById("nationalLandmarksApp").innerHTML += totalLandmarkHTML;
        //console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
    });
}

function createLandmarkPage(landmark){
    //console.log("Assembling Pages");

    var landmarkPageHTML = "";
    landmarkPageHTML += '<section id="' + landmark.landmarkLink.substring(1, landmark.landmarkLink.length) + '" data-role="page" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-header-fixed">';
    landmarkPageHTML += '<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="appHeader">';
    landmarkPageHTML += '<a href="#landmarks" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>';
    landmarkPageHTML += '<h1>' + landmark.landmarkName + '</h1></header><div data-role="content">';

    //Location
    landmarkPageHTML += '<p><span class="sectionTitle">Location: </span>' + landmark.landmarkStreetAddress + '</p>';

    //Description
    landmarkPageHTML += '<p><span class="sectionTitle">Description: </span>' + landmark.landmarkDescription + '</p>';

    //Photo of Landmark
    landmarkPageHTML += '<img src="' + landmark.landmarkPhoto + '" class="sectionPhoto"><br/>';

    /*NEED TO IMPLEMENT MAPPING API BELOW AS THIS IS JUST A PICTURE*/
    //Map of Landmark
    landmarkPageHTML += '<img src="mapDemo.gif" class="sectionPhoto">';

    landmarkPageHTML += '<div id="map"></div>';
    landmarkPageHTML += '</div><div class="bottomNotSelectedTabBar"></div></section>';

    console.log(landmarkPageHTML);
    return landmarkPageHTML;
}
```

Screenshot of Problem:

[image: screenshotOfProblem]

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't add classes `class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-header-fixed"`. JQM adds them once page is created before viewing it for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed them, however, the visual error is still occurring (I have also updated the files on the web server). Is this a problem with JQM?